# SOAP UI - 403 Error - You don't have permission to access /my-webservices/serviceName/ on this server

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I sent a SOAP webservice request using SOAP UI and I got this error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>403 Forbidden</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Forbidden</h1>
      <p>You don't have permission to access /paga-webservices/businessService/on this server.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was: SOAP-UI added a port number (443) to the URL like

```
https://example.com:443/my-webservices/serviceName
```

Hence, removing the port number with the colon (:) solved the issue.

```
https://example.com/my-webservices/serviceName
```

Comment: Are you sure it was soapUI that added the URL and this port was not in the WSDL?